# PHP match data into array

Tags: php

I'm not sure if there is some kind of php function that will help me do this fairly simply or not.  I figured I'd ask.

Let's say I have 5 products [prod1, prod2, prod3, prod4, prod5]

All of these products are related to eachother, so I need to arrive at something like this:

`prod1, prod2, prod3, prod4, prod5`

`prod2, prod3, prod4, prod5, prod1`

`prod3, prod4, prod5, prod1, prod2`

`prod4, prod5, prod1, prod2, prod3`

`prod5, prod1, prod2, prod3, prod4`

echo, save as variables, it doesn't matter to me.

In my example I said 5, but in reality there could be any number of products.  Is there a function that does this automatically up to `n` products??  I don't even know what to really call this other then I'm matching them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution:

```
$array = array('$prod1', '$prod2', '$prod3', '$prod4', '$prod5');

$result  = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $result[] = array_merge( array_slice($array, $i), array_slice($array, 0, $i)  );
}
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => $prod1
            [1] => $prod2
            [2] => $prod3
            [3] => $prod4
            [4] => $prod5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => $prod2
            [1] => $prod3
            [2] => $prod4
            [3] => $prod5
            [4] => $prod1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => $prod3
            [1] => $prod4
            [2] => $prod5
            [3] => $prod1
            [4] => $prod2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => $prod4
            [1] => $prod5
            [2] => $prod1
            [3] => $prod2
            [4] => $prod3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => $prod5
            [1] => $prod1
            [2] => $prod2
            [3] => $prod3
            [4] => $prod4
        )

)
```

Comment: how can i give a name to each nested array?

Comment: How exactly. Show me by example

Comment: Sorry for the confsion.. How could this work if the initial array `$array = array('$prod1', '$prod2', '$prod3', '$prod4', '$prod5');` was multidiemsnsional: `$array = array(array('prod1a, prod2a, prod3'),array('prod4, prod5, prod6'),array('prod7, prod8, prod9'));` i don't see how to make your code dive down one layer more so that it does the setup matching only for the products that are within in nested array

Comment: got it working.  i nested the `for` inside of a `foreach` and had that select the first dimension.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
$arr = array($prod1, $prod2, $prod3, $prod4, $prod5);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    array_push($arr, array_shift($arr));
    print_r($arr);
}
```

Comment: Simple and functional... I love it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood what you want exactly, but considering that your original data is a string, you can simply call 'explode' (http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) or similar to turn it into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $products = array();
    $line= array("prod1", "prod2", "prod3", "prod4", "prod5");
    array_push($products , $line);
    print_r($products);
```